# Is there a notation for a set of angles?

Tags: notation

Suppose that $f:[0,180]\to[-1,1]$ given by $\theta\mapsto\cos\theta$

I wondered whether  there was a notation for this domain, the principle values of a trig function?

For example we would use $\mathbb{R}$ for the domain of a function of real numbers.

I had thought it may be $\mathbb {\Theta}$ but the principle values for the trig functions are different. Maybe that's why there isn't such a notation?

I ask because I'd like to stress the function converts angles to real numbers. You input an angle $180^\circ$ and output the real number $-1$

Thanks in advance for any information

**Edit** Thanks for the comment, I hadn't considered that angles are dimensionless.  Perhaps this is why there isn't such a notation? However I think the question  still stands but perhaps worded differently. Is there a specific notation for those intervals of the real numbers that could be the domain of a trig function for example $[0,\pi] $?

Comment: Mathematicians do not use degrees, they use radians. Hence angles *are* just numbers of the interval $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: @Siminore Thanks for the comment I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: I cannot t understand your question. Why would you like a notation for $[0,2\pi]$?

Comment: Originally inspired  from a maths educators question about teaching domain  and coo domain.  I just wondered if there was such a notation.  I liked the idea of inputting in something into a function and getting out a different type if thing. The more different the better.